# Why is my SDHC card disappearing from the file system after few minutes?

Tags: file-management, sdcard

My Nikon sdhc memory card is showing in my computer, but after a few minutes it disappears from the file system. The three things I tried are:

1. formatted the card
2. changed my card reader
3. changed the used USB Port

None of the things above helped with the problem. What could be wrong and how do I prevent it?

Comment: What operating system are you on and what exact card are you using ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general computing hardware problems that are indifferent to photography.  It may be answerable here, but is probably a much better fit for SuperUser.

Comment: If my guess is right — that it's photo workflow software that is to blame — I think it's not _quite_ a general problem and would be fine here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what operating system or software you are using, but here is my suspicion: some program is configured to detect the insertion of a memory card and to look on that card for new images to import. When you insert the card, it does this, *and then automatically unmounts the card so it can be safely removed*.

If you don't want this, you can probably find the offending program and configure it to *not* run on card insertion. Alternatively, you could leave that feature active but see if the software has a configuration options to disable unmounting after import.